# Is there a limit on the amout of Azure Blob Storage SAS keys generated per hour?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

According [to this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets) detailing the limits of Azure Storage, there is a limit on the number of Azure Resource Manager requests that can be made.

Additionally, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-request-limits) details limits of the ARM API. A post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083874/azure-api-throttling) claims they ran into issues running a list operations after making too many requests.

My question is, is there a limit on number of SAS Keys generated per hour for blob storage? Is creating a SAS Key an ARM event?

For example, if I'm using the Python Azure Storage SDK and I attempt to create 160,000 SAS keys in one hour for various blobs (files in containers in storage accounts), will I be throttled or stopped?

My application depends on these keys for allowing micro services access to protected data, but I cannot scale this application if I cannot create a large amount of SAS keys in a short period of time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Creating a SAS token does not interact with the Azure Api at all -

From [Using shared access signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1)

> The SAS token is a string you generate on the client side  A SAS token you generate with the storage client library, for example, is not tracked by Azure Storage in any way. You can create an unlimited number of SAS tokens on the client side.

I couldn't find code for building a Storage SAS token, but the the principal is similar to the following (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token))

```
private static string createToken(string resourceUri, string keyName, string key)
{
    TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    var expiry = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + week);
    string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
    var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);
    return sasToken;
}
```

Basically a SAS token is a hash of the storage credentials, that are locked down to provide a subset of services. You can create as many as you require without any interaction with the Azure API.

Comment: I see! So the account key is used for signing the generated SAS key on the client side. Since it is a client side operation, it is not an ARM event and is not counted against the ARM limits.

I feel silly that I did not realize this. Especially considering that the SAS stands for Shared Access _Signature_ and for not reading the documentation more thoroughly. Thank you for your answer.